# Whats wrong with using 'INTERSECT' in this SQL code

Tags: sql, intersect

```sql
(
 Select Movie_Name
 From Theatres Inner Join Movies
 On Theatre_Movie_ID = Movie_ID AND Showing_Time = '9:00PM'
) 

INTERSECT 

( 
 Select Movie_Name
 From Movies
 Where Duration = '2:20' 
)
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses?

Comment: What is the error you get? The parentheses are useless, but shouldn't result in an error

Comment: You're already joining to movies in the first query, why not add the criteria to your join?

Comment: What is the motivation for using `intersect`?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @jason-goemaat above. Since there's already a JOIN with Movies we can add a WHERE clause for the Duration:

```
 Select Movie_Name
 From Theatres Inner Join Movies
 On Theatre_Movie_ID = Movie_ID
 Where Movies.Duration = '2:20' AND Theatres.Showing_Time = '9:00PM'
```

Comment: Not quite the same semantics as the original. If there are multiple movies of the same name

Comment: If you want unique movie names add `DISTINCT` as in `Select DISTINCT Movie_Name`...

Comment: That isn't the issue. There are two different movies with the name "Bad Boys" - 1983 and 1985. The query in the question will return the name "Bad Boys" if one of the movies has a duration of '2:20'  and the other move is showing in theatres at 9PM. The proposed rewrite won't return it in this case - hence not quite same semantics

Comment: Yes right. Looking at the implications I suspect that this is more desirable in a real world scenario than the original output.